# SQL Most recent row

Tags: sql, date, join, max

Having a bit of difficulty with this one.. I'm trying to get the most recent record based on Region and Product.

I've tried:

```
SELECT T.Region, 
       T.Product, 
       T.Date, 
       T.Revenue, 
       T.Cost, 
FROM Table as T    
Inner Join (
    Select Region,
           Product,
           Max(Date) as Date
    FROM Table
    Group By Region, Product) as X
  On T.Product = X.Product
 And T.Region = X.Region
 And T.Date = X.Date
```

Table:

```
Region  Product Date        Revenue Cost
A       X       10/1/2015   21967   0
A       X       1/31/2016   19935   19935
A       Z       1/1/1987    20356   0
A       Z       10/1/1994   20356   0
B       X       1/31/2016   19942   19942
B       X       2/1/2016    21238   0
B       Z       1/1/2004    19942   0
B       Z       10/1/2014   19942   0
C       Z       1/1/1987    20354   0
C       Z       4/1/2002    21972   0
C       Z       1/31/2016   21972   21972
```

Desired Results:

```
Region  Product Date        Revenue Cost
A       X       1/31/2016   19935   19935
A       Z       10/1/1994   20356   0
B       X       2/1/2016    21238   0
B       Z       10/1/2014   19942   0
C       Z       1/31/2016   21972   21972
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?  What database are you using?

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Answer (score 0):

Although your method can work, this is much easier with the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
SELECT T.Region, T.Product, T.Date, T.Revenue, T.Cost, 
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Region, Product ORDER BY Date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Table t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Your version should also work.  If it doesn't, it might be due to the date format.  Are you storing the dates using native date/time formats?  Or, are you using an inappropriate format such as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the original wasn't including a filter where Type = 1.

```
Region  Product Date        Revenue Cost    Type
A       X       10/1/2015   21967   0       1
A       X       1/31/2016   19935   19935   0
A       Z       1/1/1987    20356   0       1
A       Z       10/1/1994   20356   0       0
B       X       1/31/2016   19942   19942   1
B       X       2/1/2016    21238   0       0
B       Z       1/1/2004    19942   0       1
B       Z       10/1/2014   19942   0       0
C       Z       1/1/1987    20354   0       1
C       Z       4/1/2002    21972   0       0
C       Z       1/31/2016   21972   21972   1
```

This query seems to still pick up the maximum date regardless of type instead of filtering where Type= 1

```
SELECT T.Region, 
       T.Product, 
       T.Date,
       T.Type,
       T.Revenue, 
       T.Cost, 
FROM Table as T    
Inner Join (
    Select Region,
           Product,
           Type,
           Max(Date) as Date
    FROM Table
    Group By Region, Product, Type) as X
  On T.Product = X.Product
 And T.Region = X.Region
 And T.Date = X.Date
 And T.Type = X.Type
 WHERE T.Type = 1
```